# How can we tell what our gifting, calling and anointing are?

Tags: jesus, paul, elijah, elisha

What is gifting, calling and anointing of the Holy Spirit

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.  Do you have a specific text of Scripture to consider??

Comment: @Wilson Yeboh Welcome to BH and thanks for your question. You may want to edit your question to add in where in the Bible you are quoting from. Also some indication of why you find difficulty with these words would be helpful for someone trying to answer you.

Comment: This question may struggle to be answered because anointing of people (other than Christ) is only mentioned in three places, 1 John 2:20, 27 and 2 Cor 1:21.  Apart from this, the NT is silent.  The gifts of the Holy Spirit are discussed in 1 Cor 12 and 14.

Comment: @Dottard  That is an inaccurate statement.  The NT includes more than this about anointing people _other than Christ_.  Consider James 5:14; Revelation 3:18; John 9:6, 11; Mark 6:13; and Matthew 6:17 for a few more.

Comment: @Biblasia - my references are to spiritual anointing, not physical anointing.

Comment: @Biblasia please do not answer Off Topic Questions, and remember to use the VTC button to help manage low quality content on the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not up to others to tell someone what his or her gift or calling is.  When God puts a burden on the heart to do something, it is natural to at first think that such a work is too much for oneself to accomplish and one must seek another of greater ability to do it.  But with the calling, God often bestows the ability.

A prime Biblical example of this is found in the story of the making of the tabernacle/sanctuary in the wilderness.  God gave very specific directions to Moses as to how this should be done, but it required expertise in working with gold, wood, and other materials--expertise that would have been virtually impossible to find among all the formerly downtrodden slaves in Egypt.  What craftsmanship could they have mustered?

But God, the Master Craftsman, gave skill to a specific Israelite for this purpose.

> <sup>30</sup>And Moses said unto the children of Israel, See, the LORD
> hath called by name Bezaleel the son of Uri, the son of Hur, of the
> tribe of Judah; <sup>31</sup>And he hath filled him with the spirit of
> God, in wisdom, in understanding, and in knowledge, and in all manner
> of workmanship; <sup>32</sup>And to devise curious works, to work in
> gold, and in silver, and in brass, <sup>33</sup>And in the cutting of
> stones, to set them, and in carving of wood, to make any manner of
> cunning work. (Exodus 35:30-33, KJV)

Wow!  Bezaleel was given some *amazing* skill and artistic ability to be able to make the special things for the worship of God in His holy sanctuary.  He didn't even go to school to get this ability.  As a son of the tribe of Judah, he had just barely emerged from slavery as all the others--probably making bricks like all of them.  Where did this skill come from?

God, who created us, also creates our abilities.  If He puts a burden in our heart to do something, He will give us what we need to accomplish it.  It may not seem as wonderful as what someone else might do--but that someone else is busy doing his or her own work, and would have been unable to do this one, too.

No one but God can help us know what our gifts are.  It is often the case that others will think we cannot do something.  They will say discouraging things.  If we allow such thoughts and words to turn us aside from the duty God has given, we may never realize the ability He was prepared to grant that would be equal to the need.

Answer (score 2):

Spiritual anointing, calling and gifting are all integral to the work of the Holy Spirit in those called to be born again of the Spirit, from above.

As there is a dearth of detail in the question, this answer will be succinct, in the hope that the OP then adds details, such as a biblical text, which this site usually requires. (Otherwise, the question might be transferred to the more general Stack Christianity site.)

The answer simply put is this: all those who are born again (spiritually) and who become part of the family of God in the sense of John chapter 3, have that anointing which enables them to discover their calling, and they discover as they start to exercise that calling that they have also been given the gifts necessary to perform that calling.

This answer has a link to the scripture:

> "And we know that all things work together for good to them that love
> God, to them who are the called according to his purpose. For whom he
> did foreknow, he also did predestinate to be conformed to the image of
> his Son, that he might be the firstborn among many brethren. Moreover
> whom he did predestinate them he also called: and whom he called, them
> he also justified: and whom he justified, them he also glorified."
> Romans 8:28-30 A.V.

However, that may not be a text in the mind of the OP, so more detail is needed to allow for specific answers to a specific text.